# sw-text-editor field doesn't shop up as config field

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to add an wysiwyg field with the sw-text-edtior component for my cms-element as an config field, but it doesn't show up at all. If I try an sw-text-field instead of an sw-text-editor component it does show up. I can't seem to find it in the docs if I am missing something.

**My code:**
*config/sw-cms-el-config-collapse.html.twig*

```
{% block sw_cms_element_collapse_config %}
    <sw-text-editor
        v-model="blockContent"
        :allow-inline-data-mapping="true"
        sanitize-input
            @element-update="onElementUpdate">
    </sw-text-field>
{% endblock %}
```

*config/index.js*

```
import template from './sw-cms-el-config-collapse.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.register('sw-cms-el-config-collapse', {
    template,

    mixins: ['cms-element'],

    computed: {
        blockContent: {
            get() {
                return this.element.config.blockContent.value;
            },
            set(value) {
                this.element.config.blockContent.value = value;
            },
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        createdComponent() {
            this.initElementConfig('s7-collapse');
        },

        onElementUpdate(element) {
            this.emitChanges(element);
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors in the browser's error console?

Comment: @Alex I did. Noticed that I can only view readable console errors while watching the administration. 
I Eventually found out that the issue was a missing parent wrapper in the html, because vue can't render multiple top level elements.

Comment: Your `<sw-text-editor>` has a closing tag of `<sw-text-field>` which may be a typo when adding on SO, but if not that will be the cause.

Comment: "@JellevanAmersfoort in such cases you should provide an answer to your own  question and mark as answered. Helps people looking this up & people who look for unanswered questions. Coming from someone who has been here twice already :)

Comment: @JellevanAmersfoort, thanks! That was precisely the solution for me!